# Why Deep Qlearning is better than Qlearning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

If Q-learning is supposed to converge toward the optimal policy, how is it possible to do better?

Comment: Who says it is? – *Reviewer*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q-Learning stores the states and expected rewards for taking possible actions at those states in a table. That table can become very large if the state-action space is large.

Deep Q-Learning uses a neural network instead of a table. This makes it possible to apply reinforcement learning to complex domains with large state-action spaces.